# Dynamic comment system in different web pages

Tags: php, mysql, comments

I have made a dynamic web page in which I want to make a dynamic comment system for different webpages and my coding is like this:

**home.php**

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","writersplanet");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY RAND()";
$execute = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)) {



    $query_string = http_build_query($row);

    echo "<div class='container' align='center'>
        <a href='readbook.php?$query_string'>
        <div class='box'>
                <div class='imgbox'>
                    <img src='upload/".$row['uploadcoverimg']."'>
                </div>
                <div class='content'>
                    <h3>".$row['bookname']." <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i>".$row['uname']."</h3>
                    <p>".$row['summary']."</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class='outcome'>
            <div class='heart'>
                <i class='fas fa-heart'></i>
            </div>
            <div class='eye'>
                <i class='fas fa-eye'></i>
            </div>
             <div class='ratings'>
                <i class='fas fa-star-half-alt'></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='scrollmenu1'>
            <a href='#home' >Horror</a>
            <a href='#news' >Sci-Fi</a>
            <a href='#contact' >Love</a>
        </div>
        <div class='content1'>
                <h2>Time</h2>
                <p><br>
                    Writers Thoughts about this book:
                    ".$row['thoughts']."
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
?>
```

In home page when you click on a link it will take you to a new web page where you can comment. Now link page after clicking on link it will take you to readbook.php and here its coding:

**readbook.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","writersplanet");
function setcomments($con)
{
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $uname = $_SESSION['username'];
        $bookname = $_SESSION['bookname'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comments(uname,bookname, subject, time) VALUES ('$uname','$bookname','$message','$date')");
    }
}
function getcomments($con)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $bookname = $_SESSION['bookname'];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($bookname =$row['bookname']) {
            echo "<div class='usercomment'>";
            echo "<p class='uname'>";
            echo $row['uname'];
            echo "</p><p class='time'>";
            echo $row['time'];
            echo "</p>";
            echo "<div class='commentbox'><p class='subject'>";
            echo $row['subject'];
            echo "</p></div>";
            echo "</div>";
            }
        }
}
```

The problem in this script is that whenever I am posting a Comment on a Webpage_1, the comment is being displayed in all the webpages.
Please someone help me!!

Comment: Okay, what's the problem, then?

Comment: Sir if a user is writing a comment on a webpage_1, then it shows comment in all the other webpages. Here is the problem

Comment: Can you mention your problem in your question please?

Comment: Ok sir but do you know this answer?